# Aggregate and Query the RSS feeds, simply quickly and save the queries

Tags: jquery, rss, feed, aggregation

Ok I know about YQL, Yahoo Pipes and all that. But I am wondering what is the "shortcut" for someone who knows jQuery and javascript and JSON pretty well ? What would be the architecture of the generic solution using these tools to aggregate several rss feeds, and then query the result ?

I would like to be able to save these queries and send them to specific users, as url's. Yes, I know this "smacks" of Yahoo "Console" but that is way too much code behind, just to make GUI etc.

Or is there some "magic bullet" already? Some jQuery plugin or similar "thing" ? At least for the part of task ?

Thanks --DBJ

Answer (score 0):

The reason YQL or Yahoo Pipes are so efficient, is because they open up cross domain communication using JSONP or similar implementation. The reason straight JS and jQuery cannot be used to accomplish this is because of the cross domain restrictions.

You could use a proxy on your own server to fetch the feeds, and then aggregate them in JavaScript, but it seems it would somewhat defeat the purpose of what you were looking to accomplish in pure JS.

One more alternative to grabbing an RSS feed is the [Google AJAX Feed API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/) which I have used before.

Comment: I already have an HTA solution from which I can reach any domain I want. I used jQuery and it is very short and sweet solution. But when it comes to querying the result it becomes messy (of course). Especially when the real content is inside html or text which is inside the RSS. Theoretically I could use XPATH queries, but that would finihs with me developing a feed query language. I am asking is there such a thing already available? In the form of api/library ? 
YQL and Y-Pipes require the whole run-time environemnt.